# C++ program using a c library - Converting a smart pointer to a raw c style pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I am using a c library in a c++ program.

A function in the library requires pointers to both array and scalars as arguments, for example:

```
int PartGraphKway(idx t *nvtxs, idx t *ncon, idx t *xadj, idx t *adjncy,
    idx t *vwgt, idx t *vsize, idx t *adjwgt, idx t *nparts, real t *tpwgts,
    real t ubvec, idx t *options, idx t *objval, idx t *part);
```

I currently just use `new` and `delete`, to create the structures, populate them and pass them to the method.

I want to use smart points in my C++ program. Could I create smart points and convert them to raw pointers as I pass them to the function?

Therefore, I won't need to call `delete`.

Comment: C++ is very flexible: you can either use it to invent artificial problems that doesn't exist outside the language itself. Or you can use your favourite, bug-free container class and focus on writing the actual program.

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` is probably a good choice if you need to dynamically allocate an array. You can get a raw pointer to the internal buffer using `std::vector::data`.

Example:

```
std::vector<t> nvtxs(....);
PartGraphKway(nvtxs.data(), ....);
// no need to call delete; vector takes care of memory
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on who releases the pointer. If the C++ code releases it, then [`std::unique_ptr::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) will provide the raw pointer, and the object will still be automatically freed when the `unique_ptr` object is destroyed.

If the C code takes ownership of the pointer, then eventually it will use `free()` to release the memory. You can call [`std::unique_ptr::release()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) to have the smart-pointer relinquish its object ownership. 
You also have to create the pointer(s) with malloc (instead of `new`), and pass a custom deleter to the `std::unique_ptr`, for calling `free(ptr)`. If the object has a constructor, you'd have to call the [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new), in order to invoke the constructor after the `malloc`.

Comment: I think this is reading too much into the question. I'm pretty sure as asked the c function doesn't deef free the object. Hence `::get()` and a simpler answer will suffice.

Comment: @MikeVine the question explicitly says *Therefore, I won't need to call `delete`*

Comment: Yes, as I read it the callee is calling delete after the call.

Comment: @MikeVine the callee is written in C, so the callee calls `free()`. It is UB to call `free` after `new`.

Comment: @eerorika I have updated the answer to reflect your concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use smart pointers the way you want. Both unique_ptr and shared_ptr will let you read the raw pointer and pass it as an argument for zero effort.

Given you are already doing the memory management with new and delete, the other voiced concerns are not an issue?